# CSS background linear gradient bug using Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, gradient, linear-gradients

```css
html {
  background:#ffffff;
}
body {
  height:250px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #ffffff 0px,
    #ffffff 100px,
    #0065A2 100px,
    #0065A2 145px,
    #074A8B 145px,
    #074A8B 163px,
    #0065A2 163px,
    #0065A2 203px,
    transparent 203px
  );
}
```

I am trying to use a background linear gradient and with great surprise it works good on Firefox and IE but not on Google Chrome.

The code is here for example: https://jsfiddle.net/be1rgpez/1/

```
background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #ffffff 0px,
    #ffffff 100px,
    #0065A2 100px,
    #0065A2 145px,
    #074A8B 145px,
    #074A8B 163px,
    #0065A2 163px,
    #0065A2 203px,
    transparent 203px
);
```

I need a linear gradient with several color stops, but using Google Chrome it renders a strange shadow between colors (see image left box). The effect I need is "striped" without shadows).

In the attachment I show what I see using Chrome. **The left box is what I need but without the shadows (like in the right box)**. The same jsfiddle renders correctly on Firefox and IE.

[image]

**UPDATE**: this is a zoomed picture. As you can see, the left box has a small shadow between the white and the blue color (and also between other colors).

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about gradients, but it works if you use % instead of px's.

Comment: @Pete in the image attached the left box show a small shadow between colors. I need the effect on the right box, without shadow between colors (white and blue). But I need it with more colors (white, blue, dark blue...). Google chrome seems to render that small shadow when using more than 2 colors (or 2 stripes).

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
.left {
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 100px, #0065A2 100px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 100px, #0065A2 100px);
}

.right {
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 100px, #0065A2 100px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 100px, #0065A2 100px);
}
```

Comment: this code only have 1 color change (from #ffffff to #0065A2) and it works on chrome. But I need more color changes: #ffffff, #0065A2, #074A8B, then again #0065A2 and transparent at the end. Several colors seems to have a buggy behavious on chrome (like i wrote in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I found that there's an issue between **linear gradient** and **containers overflow**.
I tried many solutions and it didn't work.

Then when i tried to give `overflow:auto`, it worked for me.

[this is before i apply the fix to the right container which holds many content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bi8g.png)

[this is after applying the overflow: auto !important; to the right container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siEgh.png)
and it works fine now without any issue and here it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the same starting points two times for different colors. The below code without the duplicates looks fine:

```
.left {
     background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        #ffffff 0px,
        #0065A2 100px,
        #074A8B 145px,
        #0065A2 163px,
        transparent 203px
    );
}
```

Comment: This code generates gradients. I need stripes with net color changes. No gradient needed. This is why I am using the same pixel "stops": so I can chagne the color without the smooth/gradient effect.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8426/gradient-banding-in-chrome